# How to save a value to an sql databse using an onfocus() function via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

Basically what I am trying to do is save one value from a form into a sql database when a user focus's on another input. I guess the best way to do this is using ajax. (hope that makes sense!) here is my code:

the script:

```
   function storeLocation() {
       location = $("#location").val();
       $.ajax({
           url: 'storeLocation.php',
           type: 'post',
           data: 'feed_id=' + location,
           success: function (result) {}
       });

   }
```

the html:

```
<form id="profile" action = "index.php" method="post" name="profile">
    <input type="text" name="location" id="location" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and the StoreLocation.php code:

```
<?php 
require 'core.php';
require 'connect.php';

$city = $_POST['feed_id'];
$idPerson = getfield('idPerson','person');

$query = "UPDATE table SET idLocation = '$idLocation' 
WHERE idPerson = '$idPerson'"; 
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

Currently this code just moves the user to a new url with the variable $city for example: 
www.example.com/london.

Any help would be amazing as I've been stuck on this for tooo long:)

extra code requested:

```
    $term=$_GET["term"];


    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM venue WHERE name like '%".$term."%'
     ORDER BY name ");
     $json=array();

        while($name=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
             $json[]=array(
                'value'=> $name["name"],
                'label'=>$name["name"]
                    );
              }

     echo json_encode($json);

    ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried the onblur attribute? The _blur_ event fired, when the element losts it's focus. `<input type="text" name="location" id="location" autocomplete="off" onblur="storeLocation();">`

Comment: Thank you your response. Unfortunately that didn't fix it. it still redirects the user which I don't want to happen! thank you though

Comment: You have to add onclick="return false;" to the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the functionality you were looking for.   My example and explanation below:

Assume two tables:

1) states -> id varchar(2) (AL, MN, FL, etc..) and state varchar(32) (alabama, minnesota, florida, etc...)

2) cities -> id int(5) autoinc, city varchar(64) (Mobile, Stillwater, Miami), and state_id varchar(2) (AL, MN, FL)

Tables linked by: cities.state_id = states.id

Let's take a look at the form now.

// autocomplete.php

Call what you need for JQuery in the head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Set up your form in the body.  The state input will call a javascript function when focus moves away from the field at which point it will retrieve the cities associated with that state.

```
<form action="#">
    <label for="state">State: </label>
    <input type="text" name="state" id="state" onBlur="getCities();"/>

    <label for="city">City: </label>
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city"/>
</form>
```

*Below* the form in the body, work the Jquery magic.   I figure if you're going to use autocomplete, set it up to work *before* the user has input any location data, in this case "state".  We do this by encapsulating the code into functions.

Keep in mind that what is happening is that autocomplete is calling a php file via GET, which returns an array of values that autocomplete uses to fill the list as you type.

We want to get *all* the cities at first THEN once the user has input information in the state field get all the cities associated with that state.   Essentially we'll be setting up autocomplete twice.

Here you go - function to handle autocomplete:

```
// set autocomplete
    function setAutocomplete(data) {
        $('#city').autocomplete({
            source: data,
            minLength: 1
        });
    }
```

Now set up autocomplete, displaying all cities.

```
// autocomplete default
    setAutocomplete('getautocomplete.php');
```

At this point if you start typing in the cities input field you'll see all the cities, regardless of state.

Now we'll handle what happens when the user enters a state in the state input:

```
// get cities based on state input    
    function getCities() {
        var state_name = $('#state').val();
        setAutocomplete('getautocomplete.php?state='+state_name);
    }
```

And that's it!   When you enter state's name and lose focus on that field, it will alter autocomplete on the state input field, calling getautocomplete.php again but filtering by state name this time.

Let's take a look at the PHP file now.

// getautocomplete.php

From the top ->  Set up your database connection:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'php_autocomplete');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Then set the parameters we'll need for the SQL Query.

```
// get parameters
$term    = isset($_GET['term']) ? $_GET['term'] : NULL;
$state   = isset($_GET['state']) ? $_GET['state'] : NULL;
```

Now we check if the state parameter has been set, as this determines which SQL SELECT string we use.

```
// set query dependant on if state available
if ( $state == NULL ) {
    // get all cities
    $query = 'SELECT city 
              FROM cities 
              WHERE city LIKE "%'.$term.'%" 
              ORDER BY city';
} else {
    // filter by state
    $query = 'SELECT city 
              FROM cities 
              INNER JOIN states ON cities.state_id=states.id 
              WHERE (state="'.$state.'" AND city LIKE "%'.$term.'%") 
              ORDER BY city';
}
```

And finally we return and print out the results (essentially an array) which is what JQuery autocomplete will use to populate the autocomplete list:

```
// get results
$results = $mysqli->query($query);
$json    = array();

while ( $city = $results->fetch_array() ) {
    $json[] = array( 'value' => $city['city'], 'label' => $city['city'] );
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

You don't need to use AJAX.  Autocomplete is essentially doing AJAX on getautocomplete.php already.   We just give it an additional parameter by adding ?state=state_name, and then in the PHP we account for that parameter and craft an SQL SELECT statement as required.

Here's the complete code for both files so you can see it in context without any of my comments.   I hope this helps you solve your problem.  You should be able to make this work with your tables and form.

//// autocomplete.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Autocomplete</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <form action="#">
      <label for="state">State: </label>
      <input type="text" name="state" id="state" onBlur="getCities();"/>
      <label for="city">City: </label>
      <input type="text" id="city" name="city"/>
   </form>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      // set autocomplete
      function setAutocomplete(data) {
          $('#city').autocomplete({
            source: data,
            minLength: 1
          });
      }

      // autocomplete default
      setAutocomplete('getautocomplete.php');

      // get cities based on state input    
      function getCities() {
        var state_name = $('#state').val();
        setAutocomplete('getautocomplete.php?state='+state_name);
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

///// getautocomplete.php

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'php_autocomplete');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// get parameters
$term    = isset($_GET['term']) ? $_GET['term'] : NULL;
$state   = isset($_GET['state']) ? $_GET['state'] : NULL;

// set query dependant on if state available
if ( $state == NULL ) {
    // get all cities
    $query = 'SELECT city 
              FROM cities 
              WHERE city LIKE "%'.$term.'%" 
              ORDER BY city';
} else {
    // filter by state
    $query = 'SELECT city 
              FROM cities 
              INNER JOIN states ON cities.state_id=states.id 
              WHERE (state="'.$state.'" AND city LIKE "%'.$term.'%") 
              ORDER BY city';
}

// get results
$results = $mysqli->query($query);
$json    = array();

while ( $city = $results->fetch_array() ) {
    $json[] = array( 'value' => $city['city'], 'label' => $city['city'] );
}

echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Comment: That didn't work for me:( I don't want the form to submit as There is more values to be added. I just need to access that variable half way through the form input. thank you for your help

Comment: Access?  You mean you just want to use the variable elsewhere on the page before the form itself is submitted? I'm not sure why you need to update one field at a time in the DB instead of doing the whole form at once.   Can you explain more about what you're trying to do?  Maybe you should be using javascript to pull the value of that field when you need it.

Comment: Yeah sure, I am using an auto complete feature.. and when the user types in there location when they start typing in on another input field I want the autocomplete to only show places from that location. The auto complete function uses a separate php file.. Hence why I though the best way to access that value would be to store it in sql. Hope that makes sense! thank you

Comment: So the autocomplete.php file accesses the database and pulls locations based on the users location input?  Why couldn't you just ajax the user value into autocomplete.php and pull the information you need at that point, rather than store the user input?

Comment: that would be ideal.. I had tried to do it but I wasn't really sure how.. ajax confuses me! the autocomplete code is this 

       jQuery("#endingAt").autocomplete({
  source:'autocompletevenue.php',
  minLength:1
 });

      $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM venue WHERE name like '%".$term."%' ORDER BY name ");
 $json=array();
 
    while($name=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         $json[]=array(
                    'value'=> $name["name"],
                    'label'=>$name["name"]
                        );
    }
 
 echo json_encode($json);

Comment: Oh thats horrible to read.. whats the best way to show you that code?

Comment: Edit your question to include that code or "Add Another Answer" below.  I'll take a look at it when I have another moment.

Comment: I think I understand what you want, but give me some time to look into it and craft an answer.  I think you might be over-complicating it, but I want to test some similar code on my servers to see if what I'm thinking works.  But at a glance I don't know where you're getting $term=$_GET['term'] line.  Like I said, I know what you want and I'll edit my answer to show a solution, unless someone beats me too it.

Comment: You are the best! yeah to be honest neither do I.. must be from the jquery plugin.. Heres the link I used to get the auto complete working http://phpseason.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/php-autocomplete-tutorial-using-jquery/ thank you again.