# Jquery database results as writing?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to make a search function that retrieves data from my database. The results of this search is displayed under the input element and I need it to update as the user is writing. Can someone point me in the direction of a tutorial or simply help me understand how this would be created?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use something like jQuery UI autocomplete.   I helped someone with a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686968/how-to-save-a-value-to-an-sql-databse-using-an-onfocus-function-via-ajax/21687466).